# Magento2.22 In sitemap.xml inside more than product url getting like this "catalog/product/view/id/51"

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.2.2, sitemaps

I am using Magento2.2.2 and I used third-party module for URL regenerate this **Iazel_RegenProductUrl** and I apply command line through change URL

for example apply this `/usr/local/php71/bin/php-cli bin/magento iazel:regenurl -s2 51`

After cache flush than regenerate sitemap for a specific store and check it but same URL regenerate it **"catalog/product/view/id/51".**

If anyone this type of issue facing please reply to me because out website three store us UK and Italy.

In sitemap not generated same name multiple product url not generated and showing this url catalog/product/view/id/51 how to fix it in sitemap inside

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this "OlegKoval/RegenerateUrlRewrites" module, it will work

Comment: how we apply command for specific store wise define product id

Comment: please one example for sent to command line through regenrate

Comment: please visit this url - https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: I visit it this plugin but i ask to you how to specific store wise product id pass on command through i apply in this steps but command not working